# How can I make the app space common for all the different modules (dependent services) I run

Tags: jar, code-injection, applicationcontext

Means I have three different services in to which my application is divided and having their own Datasource connection factory, data handler and all are having their data source different with min pool size , max pool size defined for them.

Now if I make the jars use internally and use as an integrated application, how will it become a common app space for this.

What are the steps i need to make this common app space available for the entire project which is integrated with these 3 different sources.

Any kind of reply is appreciable.

Comment: Use OSGi. Change the Jars into OSGi bundles, you could still use them as standalone Jars after that. Or put them on the classpath and write some gluecode.